# Java Service: What Causes Latency Response Time Spike?

Tags: java, performance

I have a very simple Java REST service. At lower traffic volumes, the service runs perfectly with response times of ~1ms and zero server backlog.

When traffic rises past a certain threshold the response times skyrocket from 1ms to 2.0 seconds, the http active session queue and open file counts spike, and the server is performing unacceptably. I posted a metrics graph of a typical six hour window where traffic starts low and goes above the problem threshold.

Any ideas on what could be causing this or how to diagnose further?

[image: cpu usage]
[image: jvm memory usage]
[image: open files]
[image: jvm memory use by pool]
[image: http response time]
[image: http traffic level]
[image: http sessions]

Comment: Without knowing the stack, it's hard to tell. What is the Java-side server (Netty ? Tomcat ? a fully fledged Weblogic ?), what is the typical unit of work (file parsing ? DB requests ?), how do the layers connect (DB connection pool ?)... What are the sizes of each pools ?  Is there any locking taking place ? Is there I/O bound activity (file system or /dev/random and the like ?) ? "Blackbox" performance monitoring is near impossible. Although it seems reasonnable, given your figures, to rule out a pure garbage collection related issue.

Comment: Java app is written in Vert.x (based on Netty). Everything is written in non-blocking fashion. Server does a very simple Redis query, writes a single line to a text file and returns an HTTP response.

Comment: Thanks... What is the redis's connection library ? Blocking ? Non blocking ? How is file I/O handled (all write to the same file with a lock ?). In a word, is it all REALLY non-blocking or is it "written in a non blocking fashion". E.g. non blocking file IO is rare, non blocking redis driver connection is not the default. There is "nothing worse" than taking a non-blocking server such as Vert.x and pass control to blocking code. You often end up blocking the server. You have to "open the box" to tell.

Comment: I'm using vertx-redis-client to access Redis. The app is really simple... I agree that it's easy to blocking operations that are hidden inside some library or API. I wouldn't have thought my app would scale as much as it has without non-blocking. I'm trying to rewrite in raw Netty and writing my own simple non-blocking Redis client.

Answer (score 0):

Your webapp will use a thread (borrowed from thread pool) to server one request.

Under stress load, many threads are created, if the number of requests exceed the capacity of the pool, they have to queue, waiting till a thread is available again from pool.

If your service is not run fast enough, (especially you're doing IO - open file), the wait time is increase, lead to slow response.

CPU has to switch between many threads hence the CPU will spike under load.

That's why they need a load balancing and many webapp to server as a service. The stress load is distributed to many subwebapp which improve the end user experience

Comment: App is written using Vert.x, a fixed thread pool, requests are handled via non-blocking code so that each thread can service many requests.

Comment: So what do you think will handle your nonblocking code? Who will run it? It does not come out of nowhere.

Comment: Of course a thread from the thread pool handles the nonblocking code. Are you suggesting to increase the thread pool size?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to diagnostic is to create load with JMeter and investigate results with Java VisualVM, Eclipse memory analyzer and so on. I don't know whether you have tried it.

Comment: My post shows graphs of the JMX metrics that tools like JMeter and VisualVM analyze. Is there any specific advantage to using those tools over what I'm using now?

I'm using Prometheus's Java client to present these metrics, they get scraped into a Prometheus metrics server, and graphed by Grafana. That seems a much nicer toolset than something like VisualVM, but if there is something specifically that I'm missing, I'd like to know.

Comment: I use VisualVM, I never used Prometheus and I don't know what it can, so I can't compare it with VisualVM.